# Prevent resize of fullscreen/viewport intro element when scrolling on mobile devices?

Tags: css, mobile

I'm doing some testing with a fullscreen intro element that has the same size as the browser window. The background contains of an image that resizes when the browser window is resized.

The problem is browsers on smaller devices like mobile phones and tablets. When you scroll down with your fingers, the upper part of the browser moves away to give place for more space to the homepage. But each time this happens, the fullscreen intro element, want to compensate for this by adding or removing the same height to the element. This creates a jumping effects that isn't nice.

Could this be fixed in some way?

I have no link to homepage, because it's only on localhost for the moment.

Im using this CSS on the fullscreen intro element:

```
body, html {
height: 100%;
} 

.fullscreen {
 height: 100%;
 height: auto;
 }
```

Comment: The second height overrides the first one. Where is the HTML you apply this to? If the intro is just an image, maybe you can set it as the (fixed position) background of the body?

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks for you answer. If I set the image to the body, won't the image gover all areas of the hompages background?